# nested dictionary based on 3 dataframe columns

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, dictionary-comprehension

im trying to build a nested dictionary based on 3 pandas df columns:

dataframe: stops
columns: 'direction' (1-2) ,'stop_num'(1-23 if the direction is 1 and 100-2300 if direction is 2),'name_eng'

what i was trying to do is:

dct = {x: {y:z} for x, y, z in zip(stops['direction'],stops['name_eng'],stops['stop_num'])}

the result i get is a nested dictionary indeed but for unknown reason i get only the last value in y:z so the dictionary look like:

{1:{1:'aaa'},'2:{100:'bbb'}}

any idea what am i doing wrong? 
what i need is a nested dictionary with two dictionaries for each direction.

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Imagine your columns are:

```
1   a   1a
1   b   1b
2   a   2a
2   b   2b
```

Now, try your code:

```
>>> {x: {y:z} for x, y, z in zip([1,1,2,2], ['a', 'b', 'a', 'b'], ['1a', '1b', '2a', '2b'])}
{1: {'b': '1b'}, 2: {'b': '2b'}}
```

You have a loop over the tuples: `(1, 'a', '1a'), (1, 'b', '1b'), (2, 'a', '2a'), (2, 'b', '2b')`.

The first element of the tuple is the "main" key of your dictionary. Thus, the dict is `{1: {'a':'1a'}}` after the first tuple.

Then comes `(1, 'b', '1b')`. The value of the main key `1` is overwritten and the dict becomes: `{1: {'b':'1b'}}`.

The next steps are: `{1: {'b':'1b'}, 2: {'a': '2a'}}` and `{1: {'b': '1b'}, 2: {'b': '2b'}}`

To avoid the overwrite, you can do:

```
>>> d = {}
>>> for x, y, z in zip([1,1,2,2], ['a', 'b', 'a', 'b'], ['1a', '1b', '2a', '2b']):
...     d.setdefault(x, {}).update({y:z})
... 
>>> d
{1: {'a': '1a', 'b': '1b'}, 2: {'a': '2a', 'b': '2b'}}
```

The idea is to create a new dict for every new main key (`setdefault(..., {})`) and to update the dict associated with the main key (`update({y:z})`).

If you want a dict comprehension, this one will work:

```
>>> {x: {y:z for k, y, z in zip([1,1,2,2], ['a', 'b', 'a', 'b'], ['1a', '1b', '2a', '2b']) if k==x} for x in set([1,1,2,2])}
{1: {'a': '1a', 'b': '1b'}, 2: {'a': '2a', 'b': '2b'}}
```

But it's far less efficient than the `for` loop because you loop once over the first column to get the main keys, then once again over all the rows, for every main key.